# Y, N and 0 all equal 0?

Tags: php, equality

```
$isClient = 0;
if($isClient == 0) echo "is client 0\n";
if($isClient == "n") echo "is client n\n";
if($isClient == "y") echo "is client y\n";
```

Considering the code above, it outputs the following

```
is client 0
is client n
is client y
```

I must be missing something here! How come 0 is equated with "n" and "y"???

[A link to the above code for testing](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0572029ddaabdcfbd2e7682f2740b74562036366)

Comment: When you use 0 without any context, it's assumed that it means false - - if you add quotes around the 0, it will compare string to the values. It's an Apples-to-Apples kind of thing.

Comment: That is why you should use `===` when possible

Comment: [PHP comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: so 0 as an integer compares as true to any string?

Comment: @kingkero You should actually use the is_* functions instead of === if you're trying to manage typecasting yourself.

Comment: @cwal If the first word in a string is an integer is numeric, then no. Ex: (int)"12 hfdj" === 12; (int)"hfdj" === 0;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are performing loose comparison (*NB*: a strict comparison is done with help of ***three*** equal signs: `===`) and in this case a string evaluates to zero because `==` is left associative, which means, that if the first operand is an integer, the second operand is typecast to an integer as well (thus `"n"` is interpreted as `0`). That is just the way PHP works.

Comment: It should be added that a string evaluates to 0 only when the FIRST character in the string is not numeric AND when converted directly to INT. A string will still evaluate as boolean true when converted to boolean.

Comment: @JRL Reworded answer =)

Comment: Yeah. If the string was "1 N" however, the string would be cast to the INT 1. It's a bit tricky sometimes.

Comment: I understand that, not that much of a newbie. I guess I just never came across an instance where this did not work. In general I found that if a string contained *something* that it could not equal an integer. Learn something new everyday! Should also be noted that I need to start using strict comparisons more often.

Answer (score 4):

Since `$isClient` and `"n"` are of different data types, they have to be converted to a common data type in order to be compared.

`(int)"y"` and `(int)"n"` both evaluate to `0`, so your equality holds. If you want to do a strict comparison, use the triple equals sign. It checks data types as well:

```
<?php

$isClient = 0;
if($isClient === 0) echo "is client 0\n";
if($isClient === "n") echo "is client n\n";
if($isClient === "y") echo "is client y\n";

?>
```

This generates the correct output:

```
is client 0
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, when you want to compare values, you need to use three equality signs (`===`), because:

> **As described in the section about expressions [see below], expression is evaluated to its Boolean value.** If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it. More information about what values evaluate to FALSE can be found in the 'Converting to boolean' section. [(Source)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

and

> One last thing worth mentioning is the truth value of expressions. In many events, mainly in conditional execution and loops, you're not interested in the specific value of the expression, but only care about whether it means TRUE or FALSE. The constants TRUE and FALSE (case-insensitive) are the two possible boolean values. **When necessary, an expression is automatically converted to boolean. See the section about type-casting for details about how.** [(Source)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php)

So your code has to be modified as follows:

```
$isClient = 0;
if($isClient === 0) echo "is client 0\n";
if($isClient === "n") echo "is client n\n";
if($isClient === "y") echo "is client y\n";
```

Outputs

```
is client 0
```